# Sending arrays from actionPerformed() to another class

Tags: java

I have a calculation in an `actionPerformed()` method in class `A`. The results are two arrays containing doubles `C[]` and `D[]`. How can I send it to another class `B`?

Answer (score 1):

There any number of ways you could achieve this.

The important parts are:

- Have a reference to `B`
- Have some kind of means for `B` to receive the values you want to send.  I'd recommend a setter method of some kind

You could also use a common model, which is essentially the same, but exposes less about `B` to `A` making it more difficult for `A` to do naughty things to `B` it probably shouldn't ;)

Comment: I'd start with the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), but this is only going to help with the basics of the language.  It would also look at [Object Oriented Design Patterns](http://www.oodesign.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You have tons of ways. The correct one for you depends on the structure of object model you use.

However, there are two basic concept you have to understand:

#### 1. What is the "intersection point".

In order for `A`'s instance (call it `a1`) to be able to communicate with `B`'s instance (`b1`), `a1` must have a way to "put his hands" on a reference to `b1`. A few example ways to do it are:

- Each `A` get's a reference to `B`'s instance as an argument to it's constructor, or another 'set' method, and then stores it as a field made for that purpose.
- `a1` and `b1` share a common instance of class `C`. `c` can be the 'parent' of both `a1` and `b1` (i.e. contain both of them), or some 'manager' component that manage a certain process in your program.
- The `static` \ `singleton` way. `B` class stores a static instance of itself, which allows reference to it from everywhere in the program.

#### 2. What is the the desired communication interface

The interface one class exposes to others should be well designed in order to achieve many important concepts, e.g.: readability of code, security and 'hiding', reliability etc. This also depends on if both `A` and `B` are stored in the same package or are internal classes of each other or are even inherited from each other.

A few standard ways to communicate are:

- Direct writing access: a field in `B` is `public`ly exposed and allows direct writing into it. this is mostly a bad behavior (a rule of thumb is that all fields should be at least `protected` if not `private`).
- `set` methods: `B` has a set method that receives the calculated data, process it and stores it in it's fields (or pass it on).
- Listening - `A` stores the calculated data in itself, and lets all of it's registered "listeners" know that a new data is available by calling an appropriate method in them. The listeners have read access to the relevant fields, or the data is passed as an argument, and then the listener (`b1`) decides what to do with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of class B and pass the result of the calculation to that instance.

This is a very basic problem and is easy to solve once you've had some experience.  You might find the wiki on [Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) useful. Its powerful stuff once you understand it.

Here's some examples for you...

```
public class ClassB{
    double multiplier;
    public ClassB(){
        //this will be called when you create an instance of class B
        //with no arguments. Also called the default constructor, or empty-arg
        //constructor.
        multiplier = 2;
    }
    public void setMultiplier(double value){
        multiplier = value;
    }
    public void calculate(double[] c, double[] d){
        //do nifty stuff, like multiply every value in c and d!
        for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++){
            c[i] *= multiplier;
            d[i] *= multiplier;
        }
    }
}

// and in your class having the action performed method...
//create an instance of class b. This will call the empty-arg constructor.
ClassB classB1 = new ClassB();
ClassB classB2 = new ClassB();
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    double[] c1 = new double[10];
    double[] d1 = new double[10];
    double[] c2 = new double[10];
    double[] d2 = new double[10];
    //call classB1 calculate method. This will multiply c1 and d1 by 2,
    //as classb1's multiplier is 2.
    classB1.calculate(c1, d1);
    classB2.setMultiplier(4);
    //call classB2 calculate method. This will multiply c2 and d2 by 4,
    //as classb2's multipler has been set to 4.
    classB2.calculate(c2, d2);
}
```

This is just a simple example of what object oriented programming can do for you.  There's a ton more to learn than this, but as you're obviously just beginning I won't overwhelm you.

Comment: @Bill, I only have two arrays c[] & d[]. Why do I need to create 4 arrays (c1, d1, c2, d2)?

Also, what concepts in Java applied to my question I do not seem to understand?

Comment: You don't need to create 4 arrays, its just for example. I'm demonstrating the power of object oriented programming. You can create multiple instances of some class, configure those multiple instances in different ways, and use them to process different arrays in different ways depending on their configuration. I created 2 arrays just for the example. Passing data between instances is the correct way to handle your problem. That's how its related to your question. Create an instance of B, and pass your data to it from ClassA.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison, I think by breaking the rules of SSCCE (especially the first S rule), you made your example hard to understand. It's better to keep it simple then demonstrate the power of OOP..

Comment: @WilliamMorrison, When I added print statement in the for loop, in class B, I am getting zeroes for both c & d, for i times of the loop.

Comment: @munir Numeric arrays are initialized to all zeros unless you assign them something else. 0 times anything is zero. Try assigning some values.

Comment: @William Morrison, c1[] & d1[] are results of the calculation in an actionPerformed() method in class A. The statement " classB1.calculate(c1, d1);" does not seem to take the calculated values?

Comment: Correct. B2 is taking a different set of values from 2 other arrays. the result of a1 could be passed to b1 if u wanted. Or not. Doesn't matter here as I'm just trying to show u different values can be passed to different instances. If u have more object oriented questions, study or ask another question on SO please.

Answer (score 0):

Try making both arrays C & D static. Making these static will allow other classes access to it. Otherwise, you should pass it through a parameter to the constructor.

Parameter Method:

```
public class A implements ActionListener{

Array C;
Array D;

Bclass B = new Bclass(C, D);

    public void actionPerformed(){
        //Do stuff to Arrays

    }

}

public class Bclass{

    Bclass(Array C, Array D){
        //This is Constructor...
    }

}
```

Static Method:

```
public class A implements ActionListener{

public static Array C;
public static Array D;

    public void actionPerformed(){
        //Do stuff to Arrays

    }

}

public class Bclass{

    Bclass(){
        //This is Constructor...
        A.C().getIndexOf("C-stuff");
        A.D().getIndexOf("D-stuff");
    }

}
```

Comment: The use of `static` in this context is not a good idea and tends to cause more problems then it solves. I know it's only an example, but I don't think, given the OP's apparent skill level, it's not a good one - IMHO

Comment: Agreed, static is a no no... :)

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer completely. Static here is a quick fix which doesn't provide the guidance a new programmer needs.